# Android: View not at the right place

Tags: android, android-layout

I got a little problem: I can't put views to the verry right or to the verry left of my screen... In the graphical layout preview of eclipse, it looks like this:

[image: Screenshot of eclipse]

If I upload it to my Galaxy Tab 3 (10.1"), it looks exactly the same...
Here's the XML-Code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

As you can see, `android:layout_alignParentLeft` and `android:layout_alignParentTop` are set to `true`...

`@dimen/activity_vertical_margin` and `@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin` have their default value of 16dp.

It don't concerns just TextViews, but also every other view I tried out. If I select other screen sizes than 10.1", the view is at the right place.

Anybody can help me?

Thank you!

Comment: Try removing the left and right paddings of our Relative Layout

Comment: Oh, that's it! Than you! But can you say me why this behaves like this? As I have written above, it's only on 10.1" like this...

Comment: As far as I know, it's from Android 4.0.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/layout"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

You have given padding to the parent layout. That's why you couldn't place your view close to left.

Answer (score 2):

Remove these lines from your RelativeLayout

```
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the paddings of your Relative Layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/layout"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >
```